# Execute jquery function upon enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay .. this is my attempt to execute a function instead of calling from it from the  tag .. thing is .. it's not working .. mind you I'm still fresh with all these *sigh*

```
        <div class="widget first">
                <div class="head"><h5 class="iFrames">Static table</h5></div>
            <table id="example" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="tableStatic">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Column 1</td>
                        <td width="20%">Column 2</td>
                        <td width="20%">Column 3</td>
                        <td width="20%">Column 4</td>
                        <td width="20%">Column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

and the script would go:

```
/* Global var for counter */
var giCount = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnClickAddRow() {
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        $("#name").val(),
        giCount+".2",
        giCount+".3",
        giCount+".4",
        giCount+".5" ] );
     $("#name").val('').focus();
    giCount++;
}

$('#name').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
       fnClickAddRow();
    }
});
```

Now, I'm trying to add new row with the value of "name" from the input upon entering. And it's not working :\ .. by the way in this example I'm using DataTables ...

Comment: No need for `(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which)` jQuery already normalizes it with `e.which`

Comment: Can you please enlighten me? I'm very new here .. you mean I could just do (e.which) instead?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, `e.which` is enough if you use jQuery.

Comment: is it right to call the function fnClickAddRow() ? because I did edit back to (e.which) and nothing seems to be happening .. sorry for being a pain in the ass :\

Comment: It's fine, but you probably need to enclose the event in DOMReady too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/eCrJc/1/

Try to put `fnClickAddRow()` and `$('#name').on('keyup'` inside `$(document).ready` and check your browser's console for any javascript errors.

Comment: Funny .. I closed the browser and run back the codes and all went fine .. thanx guys!